# OKHTTP3 Offline cache

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I want to implement cache even if there is no internet connection(Offline) but still had no success, already look many example but still no luck

```
//FeedInterceptor Class 
public static Interceptor getOfflineInterceptor(final Context context){
    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (!isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .removeHeader("Pragma")
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached")
                        .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };

    return interceptor;
}


//OnCreate Activity
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(FeedInterceptor.getOnlineInterceptor(this))
            .addInterceptor(FeedInterceptor.getOfflineInterceptor(this))
            .cache(cache)
            .build();

//After build Request
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
return response.body().string();
```

if offline the return comes as empty string.
Is there something I miss or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to reuse a cached response, it is necessary that the response itself declares itself to be "cacheable", by providing some headers (e.g., `Cache-Control: public` or `Cache-Control: max-age=3600`). Did you check if your response contains such headers?

Also, consider using the built-in constant [CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CacheControl.html#FORCE_CACHE) as a value for your [`cacheControl` setter](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.Builder.html#cacheControl-okhttp3.CacheControl-).

Finally, be aware that (quoting from [OkHttp documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching)):

> Be warned: if you use `FORCE_CACHE` and the response requires the network, OkHttp will return a `504 Unsatisfiable Request` response

## EDIT:

Here's a full example.

```
final CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
        .maxAge(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

// Interceptor to ask for cached only responses
Interceptor cacheResponseInterceptor = chain -> {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    return response.newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
            .build();
};

// Interceptor to cache responses
Interceptor cacheRequestInterceptor = chain -> {
    Request request = chain.request();
    request = request.newBuilder()
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE)
            .build();

    return chain.proceed(request);
};

// Create a directory to cache responses. Max size = 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(new File("okhttp.cache"), 10 * 1024 * 1024);

/*
 * Let's create the client. At the beginning the cache will be empty, so we will
 * add the interceptor for the request only after, for the 2nd call
 */
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cache(cache)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(cacheResponseInterceptor)
        .build();

// Let's do the call
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://httpbin.org/get")
        .get()
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.close();

// Let's add the interceptor for the request
client = client.newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(cacheRequestInterceptor)
        .build();

// Let's do the same call
request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://httpbin.org/get")
        .get()
        .build();
response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.close();

// Let's see if we had some issues with the cache
System.out.println("Is successful? " + response.isSuccessful());
```

Please note that since this is a "standalone" example, I had to do 2 calls:

1. this call uses the network to get a valid response to cache, otherwise my cache would be empty. In your case you don't need it, since normally you'd use the device data to do a "real" call; Note that here I use the network interceptor, the one that adds the header saying "ok, you can cache this response".
2. I added the interceptor that forces to use the cache. Here the network interceptor won't be used, since either the response is found in the cache, or a 504 response is returned.

Note also that **you need to close the response**, otherwise the cache won't be populated correctly.

Comment: Yeah the response doesn't have any Cache-control, is there any solution to this?

Comment: You can take advantage of the `Interceptor` mechanism to inject one of those headers manually in the response. To do so, you take the `Response` returned by `chain.proceed(request)`, you get a new builder and you inject the headers you need. That is very similar to what you did with your `Request`. Finally, you return the newly-created `Response`, and you should be able to benefit from the cache

Comment: Stuck at adding the header, do you mean after Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); or make new Interceptor? Earlier added response = response.newBuilder() and the same header as Interceptor but still had 504

Comment: @SeptianTriadi I added a working example to show you how it should be done

Comment: @SeptianTriadi did it help with your issue?

Comment: Still pending, many other things to do. I will reply after I try it. Thanks!

Comment: Is successful? always return false even with url above