# Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object when using OkHttp cache

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to cache my data from API using oKhttp and save this data into FILE. The problem is when I'm trying to use `applicationContext.cacheDir`, in my **NetworkLayer** class but it gives me an error.

- I have tried to make my **NetworkLayer** extends from **Application()** but the problem is still.
- I also tried to make some search about this problem but I didn't find anything that related. Thanks In advance.

**Here's my code**

---

**NetworkLayer**

```
class NetworkLayer : Application() {

private val BASE_URL = ""
private val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()

private fun myHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

    val httpCacheDirectory = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, "http-cache")
    val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MiB
    val cache = Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize.toLong())

    val builder = OkHttpClient()
        .newBuilder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())
        .cache(cache)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .callTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return builder.build()
}

private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(myHttpClient())
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build()

val apiService: APIService by lazy {
    retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
   }
}
```

The problem is here, at this code line

- `val httpCacheDirectory = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, "http-cache")`

---

My **CacheInterceptor** Class

```
class CacheInterceptor : Interceptor {
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val response: Response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
    val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
        .maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .build()
    return response.newBuilder()
        .removeHeader("Pragma")
        .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
        .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
        .build()
    }
}
```

---

The **Error** message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth/com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:116)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.data.request.NetworkLayer.myHttpClient(NetworkLayer.kt:26)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.data.request.NetworkLayer.<init>(NetworkLayer.kt:42)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.data.repository.ApiClient.<init>(ApiClient.kt:12)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.viewmodel.HomeViewModel.<init>(HomeViewModel.kt:16)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.fragment.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.kt:25)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.activity.MainActivity.initializeBottomNavigation(MainActivity.kt:71)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:46)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
```

---

Edit: Here's the final code

```
class NetworkLayer : AppCompatActivity() {

private val BASE_URL = ""
private val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
private val myHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

    val httpCacheDirectory = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, "http-cache")
    val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MiB
    val cache = Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize.toLong())

    myHttpClient
        .newBuilder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())
        .addInterceptor(ForceCacheInterceptor())
        .cache(cache)
        .callTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}

private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(myHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build()

val apiService: APIService by lazy {
    retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare NetworkLayer in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applicationContext.cacheDir` must call **after** `onCreate()` in `Application` class.

In your code `myHttpClient()` is calling **before** `onCreate()` so `applicationContext` is `null`.

To solve this problem you can create `retrofit` in Application `onCreate()`

Comment: Thank you, it is working now without any error. But caching not working even there's internet or not. I have updated my class code in the question.

Comment: check out my question about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562948/okhttp-caching-not-working-when-theres-internet-or-not